# response chunking with Spring MVC & JSP: how to write contents of JSP into response?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, chunked-encoding

I'm adding response content chunking for the one "heavy" page. It is written in Java with Spring MVC, using JSP for html generation. It is running on Tomcat.
Question that I have is: how do I write JSP (resulting HTML to be precise) into response? I created small jsp file with mostly static content (head). How do I write it manually to response?

```
response.addHeader("Transfer-Encoding", "chunked");
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        writer.append(/*What?*/);
        writer.flush();
// Do heavy computations
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you do not need to write the processed JSP to the response manually. Just include flushes in your JSP:

```
<% out.flush(); %>
```

From what I know, this makes the response automatically chunked. The servlet container will add the appropriate header.

Comment: can't do that because server is doing heavy computations before sending back jsp. So when JSP gets executed server is finished doing all the work and populated view parameters

Comment: So you want something like a "heartbeat" from server to client during the long running computation?